# missing arguments for method apply... Play Framework 2.4 compilation error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

> Compilation error: missing arguments for method apply in class newPost;
>    follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

I don't understand how template handling methods have to look like and what complier require of me.
https://github.com/flatlizard/blog

**controller:**

```scala
  def addPost = Action{ implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.newPost(postForm))
  }

  def createPost = Action { implicit request =>
    postForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      hasErrors => BadRequest,
      success => {
        Post.create(Post(new Date, success.title, success.content))
        Ok(views.html.archive("my blog", Post.all))
      })
  }
```

**routes:**

```html
GET        /archive/new         controllers.Application.addPost
POST       /archive             controllers.Application.createPost
```

**view:**

```scala
@(postForm: Form[Post])(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages)
@import helper._

@form(routes.Application.createPost) {
    @inputDate(postForm("date"))
    @textarea(postForm("title"))
    @textarea(postForm("content"))
    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

**UPDATE**

I solved problem adding the following imports in controller file:

```scala
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.Play.current
```

See Play 2.4 migration:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#I18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem adding the following imports in controller file:

```scala
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.Play.current
```

See Play 2.4 migration: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#I18n

**Update**

Actually this is a bad way cause here used Play.current which will become deprecated soon. Here another solution using dependency injection:

routes:

```scala
GET        /archive/new         @controllers.Application.addPost
POST       /archive             @controllers.Application.createPost
```

controller:

```scala
class Application @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi)
  extends Controller with I18nSupport{
 ...
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Answer (score 3):

#### Compilation error

Your view expects three parameters to be passed, but you are passing only one. To solve your compilation error, change the signature in your view from`@(postForm: Form[Post])(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages)` to `@(postForm: Form[Post])(implicit messages: Messages)`.

#### Parameters and views

The second parameter in your example `(content: Html)` is used when you combine several views:

**index.scala.html**

```
@(text: String)

@main("Fancy title") {
  <div>@text</div>
}
```

**main.scala.html**

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @content
  <body>
</html>
```

**Call in controller**

```
Ok(views.html.index("Some text"))
```

In this example you are passing "Some text" to index view. Index view then calls main view passing another two parameters. `title` and `content`, where `content` is the html in between the curly braces of index.scala.html (`<div>@text</div>`)

Finally implicit parameters: `(implicit messages: Messages)` must be somewhere in scope to be passed implicitly to your view. For example like this in your controller:

```
def addPost = Action{ implicit request =>
   implicit val messages: Messages = ...
   Ok(views.html.newPost(postForm))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations, but I still don't get why Play requires my template to have play.api.i18n.Messages in parameters.

Comment: As far as I can see, `Messages` is not required. You don't use it in your template. Can't you just remove the parameter in your view?

Comment: When I remove it Play throws compilation error:
Error:(7, 20) Play 2 Compiler: blog\app\views\newPost.scala.html:7: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
     @textarea(postForm("content"))
                    ^

Comment: My fault, sorry. `Messages` is required by play from helpers. See `apply` method here for example: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.textarea$. The correct signature in your view files is therefore `@(postForm: Form[Post])(implicit messages: Messages)`